# Find minor array Junit

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have a program in Java, there is minor of all arrays:

```
public int minorArray(int a[]) {
    int largo = a.length;
    int menor = 10000;  

    for (int i = 0; i < large; i++) {
        if (a[i] < minor) 
        {
            minor = a[i];                 
        }
    }

    return minor;
}
```

I have to make a test case with JUnit, to verify that I found that minor. What method would you recommend?

Comment: "Minor of all arrays"? that's totally confusing, you program computes the minimum in an array of integer values. And what are you asking for now? Which JUNT method to you use? Or how to design a test case( which is rather trivial here providing dummy data and the target value)?

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good. I need to know which method to use in JUnit.

Comment: Why isn't `minor` not initialized with `Integer.MAX_VALUE`? Otherwise the method will fail if you have an array with all values > 10000.

Comment: Since you want to test an int return value you should try `assertEquals()`

Comment: Because I only need between 1000, Florian.

Comment: I appreciate the accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for a unit test, and that is pretty simple.

Looking at your code, it seems that this method is supposed to return the minimum value of the given array. So you write tests along that public contract.

Like:

```
Whatever underTest = new Whatever(); // the class with that method

@Test
public void testWith3SortedValues() {
   assertThat(underTest.minorArray(new int[] { 0, 1, 2 }), is(0));
}
```

Where:

- assertThat is one of the JUnit asssert methods
- is() is a [hamcrest](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Hamcrest/article.html) matcher

In other words: when you know the input that goes into that method, you know exactly what should come back. So you start thinking about potential inputs (that have different "characteristics") - and simply check for the expected results.